# Stackexchange.Redis how to read from db0 of each nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have two different servers of Redis that have the same list with the name "myList"
how can I be able to read the keys of each node?

I registered my connection like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
$"{configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("RedisMaster")},{configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("RedisSlave")}"));
```

and I need to be able to read from each, something like this:

```
            var deliveryObjects = new List<RedisValue>();

            var dbs = connectionMultiplexer.GetServers();
            foreach (var db in dbs)
            {
                var list = await db.Multiplexer.GetDatabase(0).ListLeftPopAsync(RedisKey, 5000);
                deliveryObjects.AddRange(list);
            }
```